# UIView animation not working

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, animation, uiview

I have the following code to do a UIView animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mapView.view cache:NO];
[self addSubview:detailView];
[mapView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It works when I dont add the detailView.
What actually happens is the equivalent of this:

```
[self addSubview:detailView];
[mapView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: If you remove the animation block, does the view transition happen (obviously without the animation) correctly?   I am wondering if the detail view is valid?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have the order wrong. you need to remove the old subview first before adding the new one.

see reference for setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:

you can also use CATransition on the layer of a view. and then use layer animations.

if you specifically want to flip the new view you can also use presentalModalViewController method of uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your code in tutorials all the time and never works for me. I always use this:

```
UIViewController *mainViewController = [[YourMainViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewControllerToSwitchTo = [[ViewControllerToSwitchTo alloc] init];

[mainViewController presentModalViewController:viewControllerToSwitchTo animated: YES];
```

you can set the view changing style with:

```
[setModalTransitionStyle:WhateverModalTransitionStyleYouWant];
```

but make sure this goes before the transition method.

Answer (score 1):

That code won't work. From Apple's documentation:

> If you want to change the appearance
>   of a view during a transition—for
>   example, flip from one view to
>   another—then use a container view, an
>   instance of UIView, as follows:
>
> 1. Begin an animation block.
> 2. Set the transition on the container view.
> 3. Remove the subview from the container view.
> 4. Add the new subview to the container view.
> 5. Commit the animation block.

So the transition should be applied to self not your mapView, and your add/remove are in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the graphics context to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`